# Using a material style seekbar for pre-lollipop

Tags: android, material-design

I have an application that does not target **lollipop**.

I need to make a `SeekBar` as in **lollipop**.

How do i apply such theme on my `SeekBar` or create one myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no knowledge on theming but i fixed with

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

in the `SeekBar`

Comment: yeah , you are forcing android to use material design theme for the seek bar , its similar as using Appcomapt seekbar programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can you this [custom library](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar)

#### Example :

```
<org.adw.library.widgets.discreteseekbar.DiscreteSeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:dsb_min="2"
        app:dsb_max="15"
/>
```

---

Another library is [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)

#### Example

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Slider
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1E88E5"
                materialdesign:max="50"
                materialdesign:min="0"
                materialdesign:showNumberIndicator="true"/>
```